# How to enable bluetooth in hp440 go?

Tags: bluetooth

I use hp 440 go notebook. I installed ubuntu 13.10 today on my device. But bluetooth isn't working. Then I saw the FAQs and installed bluetooth manager. But still bluetooth isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows and ubuntu as dual boot.

boot into windows - turn bluetooth ON - shut down - boot into ubuntu - you will find blutooth symbol appearing on left upper corner of the screen.

This is how my problem is solved in 13.10.

But this again raises a question whether my ubuntu side of system is dependent on windows side of system?

Comment: I use only Ubuntu